# Backing up documents of TFS server

Tags: tfs

I have been given a task of Backing up of documents in TFS server. I am not sure how to proceed with this. Google search didnot return anything usable.

How can i do this. Please share your experiences.

Answer (score 1):

The Sharepoint library used by Team Explorer's "documents" folder is stored in the two STS_* databases on the SQL server.

Note that partial backups/restores are not supported in TFS 2005/2008.  Restoring just the Sharepoint databases without the other ones (especially the TfsIntegration database) would leave you in an inconsistent state.  As of TFS 2010 you can do backups/restores at the [collection level](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/04/19/team-foundation-server-2010-key-concepts.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what documents you are referring to, since TFS follows 3-tier model, will backing up databases that hold your desired data solve your problem?

Comment: I have a documents folder under my Main Site. I want a backup of that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Documents in TFS were stored in sharepoint site that gets installed when we install TFS. WSS_Content is the name of the database that holds all documents and their version history.

In my case this database was not a part of the maintenance plan in sql server.

So, I modified the maintenance plan and now this database is getting backed up along with other databases.